# Electric Oven Heating/Bake Element Wiring Burnt

Tags: wiring, oven

I've replaced these bake elements a few times but this time the wiring came off when I pulled it out & I had to retrieve it from the back & push it back thru.
The spade terminal connector is toast & I've never changed one. Where do I find one & how do I replace it? [image]

Comment: Replacing a few times and the burnt wire probably caused by a loose connection.  If easy to push on with no force, then the connection is not tight.

Comment: What happens at the auto parts store when you walk up to the counter and ask for a set of brake pads?

Comment: It's a Kenmore 790.9601

Answer (score 2):

These can be a little tricky because you'll need a high temp flag type connector. They have to be crimped so you'll need a crimping tool. The wire has been burnt so you'll need to cut off the burnt section and in doing so, you might not have enough wire to connect to the element so you'd have to replace the wire.

You're best bet on this is to remove the wire from the oven and bring it to an appliance repair store and let them match the connector and piece of wire. They'd probably crimp it for you too. This it a little more complicated than connecting a dimmer switch because of the heat and amperage involved so if you're not familiar with this type of work, get some help. You might be able to get with the manufacturer or appliance repair site and get a new wire and spades.